# The limit of $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\text{ rational} \\ -x & x\text{ irrational}\end{cases}.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ -x & x \in \mathbb{Q}^c \end{cases}.$$
>
> prove that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists iff $c=0$.

1) Suppose that $c=0$, $\epsilon >0$, and choose $\delta = \epsilon$.

If $0<|x-0|< \delta$ then $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=|x|<\epsilon$

By definition of the limit this means that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$

2) Let $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists, say $L$, and we want to show that $c=0$.

$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$, this means that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, |x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

How can I complete that, please?

Comment: You can use the contrapositive instead...so instead of showing that "limit exists $\implies L=0$", try to show that "$L \neq 0 \implies$ limit does not exist"

Comment: It is easier to prove directly that for any $c\neq0$ the limit does not exist, i.e. that there is a sequence converging to $c$ such that it's image under $f$ does not converge.

Comment: @DylanZammit Thank you so much.

Comment: @MarsPlastic Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Mars Plastic in the comments, the limit at c exists if for any sequence such that $$x_n \rightarrow c \implies f(x_n)\rightarrow L$$
We will construct such a sequence:

Note: $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^c$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so for any small distance from any number $c$, one can find a rational or irrational number.

Let $c\neq 0$

Let $x_1\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_1-c|<1$

Let $x_2\in \mathbb{Q}^c$ such that $|x_2-c|<1/2$

Let $x_3\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_3-c|<1/3$

Repeating this process an infinite number of times creates a sequence such that $|x_n-c|<1/n \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $x_n\rightarrow c$

However we can show that the sequence $f(x_n)$ does not converge if $c\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your last assertion is true for $\epsilon=\frac{|L|}{2}$. So you can choose a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\frac{|L|}{2}\iff L-\frac{|L|}{2}<f(x)<L+\frac{|L|}{2}$. Check that this forces $f(x)$ to be of constant sign for all $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, and then conclude by finding both a rational and an irrational $x$ in this ball.

Comment: Thank you so much.